# What is the recommended x length in the Diffie-Hellman algorithm?

Tags: diffie-hellman

According to [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412#appendix-E.2) & [RFC 2412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#section-3), the `prime` and the `generator` are defined, but there is no recommended length for the parameters of random number $x$. What is the recommended length of random number $x$?

In my case, I set the length of $x$ at 160 bits with a 1024- & 2048-bit `prime`.

Is it safe?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, RFC3526 does have recommendations for the random number size; see section 8, and the table listing "exponent size".

Now, it gives two different recommendations (which sounds rather less useful than giving one); the summary is that if the size of the random number you pick is $x$ bits, then an attacker can recover the shared secret with no more than $2^{x/2}$ work.  If you're happy with 80 bit security, then selecting a 160 bit random $x$ is sufficient.  If you want significantly more than 80 bit security, well, you might want to rethink the 1024 bit group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Lenstra and Verheul equations to calculate the size of the key `x`, e.g. by entering the prime size value at [keylength.com](http://www.keylength.com/en/1/): choose `Enter basic parameter` & select `Enter a discrete log group size`, enter the size in bits of your chosen prime and hit `compute`.

Note that you may want to choose something nearby that is either $2^n$ or $2^n + 2^{(n - 1)}$ just to maintain compatibility over different libraries. At a minimum you should chose something that is dividable by 8.

Alternatively you can look at the NIST and ECRYPTII recommendations, also available on the same site.

Comment: And they will - of course - about match the answer of Poncho, that's a given :)